# WPF: Comboboxes and onselect Item Propery

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF Application with two comboboxes.When I select the first one the items related  to the first combobox will be populated on the second one

Here is my select Property

```
       private void InitializeTransactionTypes()
    {
        if (_selectedApplication != null)
        {
            if (transactionTypes != null)
            {
                transactionTypes.Clear();
            }

            var getAppCode =
                ApplicationVModel.GetAllApplications().FirstOrDefault(apps => apps.Name == _selectedApplication);

            var transTypeList = TransactionTypeVModel.GetAllTransactionTypes()
                                                     .Where(t => getAppCode != null && t.Id == getAppCode.Id)
                                                     .ToList();

            _transTypeObsList = new ObservableCollection<TransactionTypeViewModel>(transTypeList);
        }
        this.transactionTypes = _transTypeObsList;

        NotifyPropertyChanged("TransactionTypes");
    }
```

Lets say I select first combobox has {A,B,C,D} ...and the second combobox has  {A'1,A'2,A'3}, when I select item from first Combobox the second combobo keeps populating 
items. I wanted to show only {A'1 for A} {B'1 for B} ...etc but now what it does is  {A'1  A'1 A'1 ..... for A} {B'1 B'1 B'1 ....for B} for every select.

How can I fix that?

Comment: In general it should work. Is suppose the second combobox is bound to 'TransactionTypes'? Have you checked that TransactionTypes contains the right ViewModels (A1, A2, A3)? Can you post the XAML?

Comment: Rather than re-create the TransactionTypes ObservableCollection each time, you should clear the collection using TransactionTypes.Clear() and re-populate via the property with the new items.

Comment: @RichardE I updated the method but still it increment